# why the localhost cannot be resolved if I try to send email using servlet

Tags: tomcat, servlets, properties-file

I have properties file js.smtp.properties :

```
mail.sender.host=localhost
mail.sender.username=
mail.sender.password=
mail.sender.from=info@mycompany.com
mail.sender.protocol=smtp
mail.sender.port=31
```

And my java class looks like this:

```
      ...


FileInputStream smtpfis = new FileInputStream("/home/webserver/tomcat6/properties/js.smtp.properties");
        smtpProp.load(smtpfis);

public void sendEmail(String recepientAdress, String userID, String randNum) throws AddressException, MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException
    {

        String from = smtpProp.getProperty("mail.sender.from");     
        String host = smtpProp.getProperty("mail.sender.host");
        String port = smtpProp.getProperty("mail.sender.port");
        String subject = "Password Change Notification";

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties);

        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recepientAdress));
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());

        msg.setContent("<p>Hi there,</p><br /><a>We received a request to reset your password. <br />To reset your password and access your account, click the link below.</a><br />"
        + "<a href=\"http://" + "devserver.myapplication.com" + ":8080/" + directoryName +"/ConfirmedResetPasswordPage.jsp?randNum=" + randNum + "&practiceName=" + practiceName + "\"> Click Here </a>"        
        , "text/html; charset=utf-8" );

        Transport.send(msg);
    }
```

How is it that localhost from properties file was resolved but in my msg.setContent() I can't make it work, but instead have to give the entire server name???

Am I doing something wrong?

Also, if I open tomcat manager, I can open these properties file and see contents, by typing:

```
devserver.myapplication.com:8080/config/js.smtp.properties
```

but if I try to change this line of code:

```
FileInputStream smtpfis = new FileInputStream("/home/webserver/tomcat6/properties/js.smtp.properties");
```

to:

```
FileInputStream smtpfis = new FileInputStream("/config/js.smtp.properties");
```

It doesn't work!!!...
Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

File operations require a full path from inside servlets.  Assuming your `/config/` folder is under your web-app's path, you need to use `application.getRealPath("/")` [in a JSP] or `context.getRealPath("/")` in a servlet, but first you must grab the context in your servlet's init method:

```
private ServletContext context;

public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException
{
    this.context = config.getServletContext();
}
...
...
FileInputStream smtpfis = new FileInputStream(context.getRealPath("/") + "/config/js.smtp.properties");
```

If config is the folder your web-app is in:

```
FileInputStream smtpfis = new FileInputStream(context.getRealPath("/") + "/js.smtp.properties");
```

Comment: I must have libraries of an older Servlet API version in runtime classpath . If I try to run these few lines of code it gives me: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletConfig
bummer :(